# Is row-major and column-major order really a property of a programming language

Tags: matrix, language-agnostic, terminology

I think I have discovered a widespread misunderstanding (professors do it wrong!). People say that C and C++ represents matrices in row-major order and Fortran column-major order. But I doubt that C and C++ have build in major-order because there is no true matrix type? If I enter

```
int A[2][3] = { {1, 2, 3}
              , {4, 5, 6} };
```

The order is row-major just because my editor is row-oriented rather than column-oriented. This has nothing to do with the language itself, or has it? If the editor were column-oriented:

```
i {
n { {
t 1 4
  , ,
A 2 5
[ , ,
2 3 6
] } }
[   ;
3 
]
=
```

Now the matrix A has two columns and three rows.

To illustrate further, consider a matrix print loop

```
for(int k=0; k<M; ++k)
    {
    for(int l=0; l<N; ++l)
        {printf("%.7g\t",A[k][l]);}
    putchar('\n');
    }
```

***Why* does it print by row?** Because '\n' moves to the next row rather than the next column. If '\n' were interpreted as "go to the next column and first row" and '\t' go to the next row, then A is printed column-wise. But I know that my terminal is row-oriented, so if I want to print column-wise, the only way is to swap these loops.

If A[k] *logically* represents a row or column depends on the functions that operates on A and then there is a trade-off what order to choose. For example gauss elimination walks `rows{column,rows{column}}`. The advantage of placing row-index first is that it makes it easer to swap rows when pivoting. However, to perform the pivoting one has to loop through all rows in the same column, which should be faster by choosing the opposite. The innermost elimination loop has access two rows at the time and neither is really good.

**A better terminology** probably is *first-index indexing* and *last-index indexing*. This is a pure language feature: First-index indexing refers to the situation when the first given index is supposed to increment slowest, while last-index indexing is the opposite. "Rows" and "columns" is an interpretation issue much like byte order and character encodings: The compiler will never know what a row or column is but it may have a language defined input order (Most languages happens to accept numeric constants in big endian order but my computer wants little endian). These terms come from conventions in the environment and library routines.

Comment: I've often thought about this too, and i agree.  It's really the order of indices that is language defined, not the actual 2d layout of data (because it's all just linear anyway). People argue violently against this opinion online, and assume you're the one confused. Whether you choose to call the first or last index a "row" is up to you.

Comment: But as a note, you'll be against the established standard... so most libraries will assume a 2d layout for your linear memory.

Comment: @JonathanOlson I have found another terminology that is quite good: AoS, and SoA. Though matrix columns does not have "names", they may be coefficients for a linear system of equations. So you can give them an appropriate name.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with how your text editor works, and everything to do with how the elements of the 2D array are laid out in memory. That in turn determines whether it is more efficient for nested loops (looping over all the elements of the matrix) are more efficient with the row loop as the inner loop or with the column loop as the inner loop.

Comment: What I am pointing at is that there is no rows or columns in the memory. All there is, is an array of digits. Rows and columns are only representation of data.

Answer (score 1):

As one commenter suggested, it's really just the order of indices in the array access syntax that makes C row-major.

Here's a better example program that initialises a 2D array using a flat list of values.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    int data[9] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    int arr[3][3];
    memcpy(arr, data, sizeof(int)*9);

    printf("arr[0][1] = %d\n", arr[0][1]);
}
```

So now we can avoid any confusion added by the 2D array declaration syntax, or how that syntax is laid out in the text editor. We are just concerned with how C interprets the linear list of values that we have shoved into memory.

And if we run the program we will see:

```
$ ./a.out 
arr[0][1] = 2
```

This is what makes C row-major. The fact that the array syntax is interpreted as [row][column] when accessing data in memory.